# Review close vote queue tag filtering produces a timeout error

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close

This issue was raised last year [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/152043), but it still happens when filtering close votes on obscure tags.

For example the [CUDA](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) tag doesn't have a lot of questions, and it has even less close votes, and right now I suspect there are no questions with close votes that I haven't already voted on or reviewed. If I filter for just that one tag, I get a 20 second delay followed by:

[image: FAIL]

I guess this is a timeout from a very slow query. In the broad scope of things it isn't a big deal, but if you are interested in "curating" a number of obscure tags on Stack Overflow (which is about all I do here), it makes things a lot more annoying than it probably should.

Comment: I just had same issue in AU.